# How to get the current user from node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, confluence

When creating a Confluence add-on with node, I want to retrieve a user's account information.

How can I get the current running user's id and name? If I just have an id of a user, how can I get their info (i.e. full name, username, profilepic, etc.)?

I found some resources on how to use it from a Java perspective ...

(1) https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-developer-faq/how-do-i-find-the-logged-in-user

(2) https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/user/UserAccessor.html

Their documentation even has how to get the id and username from the front-end:
https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/javascript/module-User.html

Though, I didn't see anything for node.

Comment: A little unfair people downvoted you... I had a quick look and there's no clear documentation about this for the JSON API. There is however documentation for the SOAP API which _apparently_ are apparently identical. Have a look at https://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#getUser(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: The SOAP API will be removed from Confluence in a future version so I would recommend staying away from that.

Answer (score 1):

In the Atlassian Connect plugin, you can retrieve the username by getting the `user_id` request parameter which is sent to your add-on.

For example, here's a call to my [Gister Macro for Confluence Cloud](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/me.davidsimpson.confluence.addon.gister) on [this page](https://dvdsmpsn.atlassian.net/wiki/display/gister/Gister+Macro+for+Confluence+Cloud):

```
https://davidsimpson.me/labs/gister-for-confluence-cloud/gister.html?gistUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Fdvdsmpsn%2Fa7910d336c5864201837
    tz=Europe%2FLondon
    loc=en-GB
    user_id=dvdsmpsn
    user_key=ff8080814b99b7f1014b99b80fda0001
    xdm_e=https%3A%2F%2Fdvdsmpsn.atlassian.net
    xdm_c=channel-gister-macro2158065749017340142
    cp=%2Fwiki
    lic=none
    cv=1.1.44
```

If you know the user's `user_id` (`dvdsmpsn` in this case), you can send a REST call e.g.

```
https://dvdsmpsn.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/prototype/1/search/user.json?query=dvdsmpsn
```

This will give a response:

```
{  
   "totalSize":1,
   "result":[  
      {  
         "id":"491522",
         "type":"user",
         "title":"David Simpson [Administrator]",
         "wikiLink":"[~dvdsmpsn]",
         "createdDate":{  
            "friendly":"Feb 17, 2015",
            "date":"2015-02-17T22:57:26+0000"
         },
         "creator":{  
            "links":[  
               {  
                  "href":"https://dvdsmpsn.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/prototype/1/user/non-system/dvdsmpsn",
                  "rel":"self"
               }
            ],
            "avatarUrl":"/wiki/download/attachments/491522/user-avatar?version=1&modificationDate=1425823096051&api=v2",
            "displayableEmail":"david@davidsimpson.me",
            "anonymous":false,
            "name":"dvdsmpsn",
            "displayName":"David Simpson [Administrator]"
         },
         "lastModifier":{  
            "links":[  
               {  
                  "href":"https://dvdsmpsn.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/prototype/1/user/non-system/dvdsmpsn",
                  "rel":"self"
               }
            ],
            "avatarUrl":"/wiki/download/attachments/491522/user-avatar?version=1&modificationDate=1425823096051&api=v2",
            "displayableEmail":"david@davidsimpson.me",
            "anonymous":false,
            "name":"dvdsmpsn",
            "displayName":"David Simpson [Administrator]"
         },
         "username":"dvdsmpsn",
         "userKey":"ff8080814b99b7f1014b99b80fda0001",
         "thumbnailLink":{  
            "href":"https://dvdsmpsn.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/491522/user-avatar?version=1&modificationDate=1425823096051&api=v2",
            "type":"image/png",
            "rel":"thumbnail"
         },
         "link":[  
            {  
               "href":"https://dvdsmpsn.atlassian.net/wiki/display/~dvdsmpsn",
               "type":"text/html",
               "rel":"alternate"
            },
            {  
               "href":"https://dvdsmpsn.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=491522",
               "type":"application/pdf",
               "rel":"alternate"
            },
            {  
               "href":"https://dvdsmpsn.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/prototype/1/content/491522",
               "rel":"self"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "group":[  

   ]
}
```

OK, this is using the "deprecated" prototype REST API, but for want of a replacement, you have to just make do with what's available.